# Is there a simple way in Javascript to run a function when a specific object property changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a third party library that gives me a reference to its object when it initialises:

```
const flktyInit = (ref) => {
    flkty = ref.flkty;

    console.log(ref.state.flickityReady) //returns false on page load, but few seconds later returns true 
  };
```

What I am trying to make sure of is before I run a method from flkty, `ref.state.flickityReady` is true first. I have achieved this in a hacky form with setInterval, but this feels too hacky and can't find an obvious answer.

FYI this app is in a React environment.

Can anyone offer up a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to use vanilla `javascript` you'll have to use `setInterval`.

Since you've mentioned that you are using `ReactJS`, and as long as this behavior related to a component, I would recommend handling it as the component `state`, so when the `state` changes (and turning from `false` to `true`), you can execute a function call using [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) (inside that `useEffect` you will have to check if the value is true or false before calling the function you want, But it will trigger `useEffect` each time the state of the component was updated.